# Is it a good idea to put all assembly: WebResource in the same cs file?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a .NET library, with some WebControls.

These webControls have Embed Resources.
And we declare them like it, in all webcontrols for each cs file:

Something like this:

```
[assembly: WebResource("IO.Css.MyCSS.css", "text/css")]
namespace MyNamespace.MyClass
{
    [ParseChildren(true)]
    [PersistChildren(false)]
    [Designer(typeof(MyNamespace.MyClassDesigner))]
    public class QuickTip : Control, INamingContainer
    {
        //My code...
    }
}
```

Would it be a good idea to create a cs file and include all WebResource declarations there?

Example a cs file with just:

```
[assembly: WebResource("IO.Css.MyCSS.css", "text/css")]
[assembly: WebResource("IO.Image.MyImage.png", "image/png")]
//And many other WebResources of all WebControls of the Assembly
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question. It depends on the project characteristics.